# writing php serverside code for image processing using ajax on frontend. PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some script that takes a form and sends it to php using jquery ajaxSubmit.

Server side must copy image from one location to another.
using this code `copy($img_dir_file,$mini_dir_file);` is ok if u have few images.

But if u have let's say 20+ images php works slowly, and responds to ajax before finishing it's job. Thus Ajax changes content to blank page , cause result is not ready.

If you refresh page a bit later, everything is ok cause php finishes his work.

So please tell me what should I do with this problem ?

script is something like this

```
$('#save_edited_article').live('click',function(){
$('#edited_article_form').ajaxSubmit({
success: function(responseimage){
$('#main_content').html(responseimage) } }); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated jQuery and ajaxSubmit plugin and everything works nice.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Promise` which will inform the browser when the job is complete.

Check out the [jqXHR Object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as part of Ajax on JQuery - you could then change your main content when the jqxhr object ( which works as a `Promise`) is complete :

```
jqxhr.done(function(){ $('#main_content').html(responseimage); });
```

#### Edit

An example using your code could be:

```
$("#edited_article_form").submit(function() {
    var jqxhr = $.post(
        "foo.php",
        $("#edited_article_form").serialize()
    );
    jqxhr.fail(function(){ alert("fail") });
    jqxhr.done(function(responseimage){ $('#main_content').html(responseimage) });
});
```

**Disclaimer : This was written on the fly and may not compile. It is for example purposes only**

Comment: sounds promissing but I'm a bit novice in ajax world , so I think jquery ajaxSubmit function is not needed anymore, instead of that I must use your object. Problem is I have a form to submit. So how can I do that ? Can you write my complete example? accroding to my code ?

Comment: The jqXHR object is part of the Ajax call, so you don't really need to change much of your code. Did you have a look at the link I sent you? The stuff about jqXHR is near the bottom and has example code.

Comment: I've read it, sorry I'm a bit novice, also my script is using ajaxSubmit script. and it submits form. In your link there is a bit different process so I'm thinking if there is possibility to combine those.

Comment: ok - I have added an example. I hope that helps you understand a little more.

Comment: Trying to use that code but for now there is some javascript error. Trying to understand what's going on...

Comment: I have changed the code in the example above, so it should not return any JavaScript errors. Here is a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8GUh/9/) which shows the code in action. The JSFiddle example does fail as the `POST` is being made to a page that does not exist (foo.php - this needs to be changed to where your php code it located)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2584/discussion-between-david-and-my-head-hurts)

Comment: system asked me to "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to  automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Answer (score 0):

Have the AJAX call check to see if it's complete, if it's not, keep polling every few seconds until it's ready.

Comment: some kind of example please ? By the way I thought success: does that work

Comment: The AJAX call would need to first check that the last command was completed. If not, respond with "not ready", which would then indicate that you need to call back in a few seconds. "success" tells you that the AJAX call was successful -- put in your own response to indicate "ready" or "not ready".

Comment: u mean I must echo ready or not ready in php ? But is I do so then where I must echo the result for ajax ? Sounds a bit complicated :( some code example would be nice explanation

Comment: I don't know PHP that well, but the technique is sound.